# Is Bootstrap 3 compatible with 508 compliance section?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, section508

My team faced some issues with recognition of **bootstrap 3** drop-down lists (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) by screen readers for visually impaired people. So I'm curious, if bootstrap 3 compatible with **508 compliance section** (http://www.section508.gov/)?

If it is not, are there any bootstrap plugins, which make it compatible with 508 section?

Comment: I'll be surprised if it is (if it's anything like the EU rules that cover similar things) but this appears to go a long way towards helping: https://github.com/paypal/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin

Comment: They do not specifically state they meet 508 Compliance on their Accessibility section ( http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#accessibility ) but they do outline resources baked in, as well as links on how to determine Accessibility issues so you can fix them with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the bootstrap dropdown menu using [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/download/) and they work properly, assuming they are properly tagged. You need to ensure that the element used for the dropdown "button" is a item that can take focus, it can't be a div or a span, and the ul needs to have role="menu".

To use the dropdown with NVDA for example you navigate using <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> and then hit enter to open the menu.

The code should look like:

```
<a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown Menu Button <span class="fa fa-caret-down">&nbsp; </span></a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" title="Link to Google">Link to Google</a></li>
    <li>Just some Text</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.stackoverlow.com/" target="_blank" title="Stack Overflow">Stack Overflow</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php and checklist from http://webaim.org/standards/508/checklist it seems that bootstrap 3 does not have any major issues with 508 compliance section.

But, unfortunately bootstrap drop-downs are not readable by screen readers in the same way as readers do it for select tags, even with https://github.com/paypal/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin. So it might be a little bit difficult for visually impaired people to select some values in long lists, e.g. select country list.